# IBM BPM 8.5 Process Designer getting hung when multiple users login to the same Process Center

Tags: ibm-bpm

We have an IBM BPM 8.5 Process Center & we are using the Process Designer locally. When multiple users try logging in to the Process Center, the local PD stops responding. With only one user, we are able to work properly. Please provide a valid solution to this. We have tried increasing the heap Size as well.

Comment: Need more data in order to understand what is going on.  Specifically -  Are there any errors listed in the server logs?  When you say "Local Process Deigner" do you mean the remote ones work okay but the on on the server isn't working?  Does this happen when you reach a certain level, or even with one additional PD connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are using the linux set up environment, try the following:

1. increase the allowable stack size inside the file "limits.conf". This is placed in the directory "etc/security". Edit and add the below snippet:

"Code"

```
# - stack - max stack size (KB)
user_name soft stack 32768
user_name hard stack 32768
# - nofile - max number of open files
user_name soft nofile 65536
user_name hard nofile 65536
# - nproc - max number of processes
user_name soft nproc 16384
user_name hard nproc 16384"
```

Check the current value by executing this command after editing: **ulimit -n**

2. Increase the **umask** value by issuing the command "**umask 077**"

Hope this helps!